# How to I implement variable step size in a for loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, variables, for-loop, increment

I want to code a for loop like -

```
for ( i=1000; i<=10000 ; i=i*1.2 )
```

How do I code this in R?

Comment: Feel free to accept one of the answers!

Answer (score 3):

Using a while loop:

```
i=1000
while (i < 10000) {
    print(i)
    i = i*1.2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i in seq(1000, 10000, 1.2)){
  print(i)
}
```

The command `seq` creates a numeric vector with values from the first argument to the second argument. the third argument specifies the step-size.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/seq

Comment: this doesn't do what the OP wants (*multiplicative* steps)

Comment: Oh i misread that as a plus sign. Then I'd suggest the answer of @jamie-mac